# Water explosion and Navier-Stokes global regularity problem

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In this [article](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/07/26/magazine/the-singular-mind-of-terry-tao.html?action=click&contentCollection=magazine&region=rank&module=package&version=highlights&contentPlacement=1&pgtype=sectionfront&_r=0), Terence Tao is talking about a water explosion thought experiment that can lead to the solution of Navier-­Stokes global regularity problem. Can anybody explain this in more mathematical terms?

Comment: What papers on the Navier-Stokes equations have you read? You'd be best advised to post those papers, so we know what level of math would appease you.

Comment: @Zach466920 as someone who has not read any none popular-science-style article on Navier-Stokes, I'm also quite curious about this idea, so do you have any 'reading list' for someone like me?

Comment: I'm familiar with the global regularity problem and have read couple of papers on it - "Regularity Criteria for the Three-dimensional Navier-Stokes Equations" , "Global regularity for some classes of large solutions to the Navier-Stokes equations" Also - https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/03/18/why-global-regularity-for-navier-stokes-is-hard/